# How to insert current date and time when user insert data in database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I  am trying to insert data into database. i am basically trying to get current date , I am also hiding that particular field("Update Date) because I do want the user to see. Now  all I am wanting is whenever i insert some data to database created date should automatically inserted.

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(StoreImageCreateVM StoreImageVM)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                StoreImageLogic.Insert(StoreImageVM);
            }
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                TempData["Failure"] = "Creation Failed. Image too large.";
                return View(StoreImageVM);
            }
            TempData["Success"] = "Creation Successful";
            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = StoreImageVM.StoreID });
        }
  return View(StoreImageVM);
    }
```

**savechangesmethod**

```
 public bool Insert(StoreImageCreateVM imageVM)
    {
        StoreImage image = new StoreImage();

        image.StoreID = imageVM.StoreID;
        image.ImageDescription = imageVM.Description;
        image.UploadDate = imageVM.uploadDate;



        //Upload the file
        string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Content\Uploads";            
        string filename = imageVM.File.FileName;
        string fullPath = Path.Combine(path, filename);

        imageVM.File.SaveAs(fullPath);

        //Set imageURL
        string serverFilePath = @"\Content\Uploads\";
        image.FullFilePath = serverFilePath + filename;
        image.Active = true;

        return base.Insert(image).StoreImageID != 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `image.UploadDate = imageVM.uploadDate` write `image.UploadDate = DateTime.UtcNow;` ??? Not really sure what you are asking here.

Comment: @Igor i am just trying to grab the current date to insert in the upload field

Comment: @Igor thanks for your suggestion but i managed to fix it

Answer (score 0):

i just add to change the savechangesmethod by using the DateTime.Now method. see below.

```
        public bool Insert(StoreImageCreateVM imageVM)
    {
        StoreImage image = new StoreImage();

        image.StoreID = imageVM.StoreID;
        image.ImageDescription = imageVM.Description;
        image.UploadDate = DateTime.Now;



        //Upload the file
        string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Content\Uploads";            
        string filename = imageVM.File.FileName;
        string fullPath = Path.Combine(path, filename);

        imageVM.File.SaveAs(fullPath);

        //Set imageURL
        string serverFilePath = @"\Content\Uploads\";
        image.FullFilePath = serverFilePath + filename;
        image.Active = true;

        return base.Insert(image).StoreImageID != 0;
    }
}
```

}